# Still getting maximum buffer size error after allow chunking in HTTP connector settings LogicApps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have allowed chunking in HTTP connection in LogicApp but still getting error: BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'.

Please find below the screenshots as well for details.

[HTTP connector of LogicApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUHsC.png)

[HTTP connector setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N5Ul.png)

Comment: Can you please help us with the flow of your logic app?

Comment: If you expect larger files, I would suggest writing an azure function for uploading files to sftp. Logic apps are not reliable for large files.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, the request made by the HTTP connector is returning a good amount of data which requires chunking. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#chunked-message-handling-for-connectors) documentation, the endpoint which you are sending the request to, needs to send partial data which would enable HTTP connector to use chunking to download the whole data.

> To download chunked messages from an endpoint over HTTP, the endpoint must support partial content requests, or chunked downloads.

> Logic Apps can't control whether an endpoint supports partial requests. However, when your logic app gets the first "206" response, your logic app automatically sends multiple requests to download all the content.

Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/62753/azure-logic-apps-large-file-handling.html) might be helpful. I came across this thread, while facing a similar problem in the SFTP connector.